# How to make script that runs a commandline with a inputbox for a variable to the command?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, vbscript, cmd, command

I'm trying to create a script (probably VBS?) that runs a start executable command, but with a variable (Number) at the end of it.

So, I want a script that makes a input box to appear, where i can enter a number and it will execute the default command + add the number i write.

The command i use atm:

```
start G:\testfolder\test.exe 1234
```

ATM i have a .BAT file that i edit manually in notepad++ when i need a different number, but i want a single file where i can just input the number inn.

Does anybody know how I can do this?:

> start G:\testfolder\test.exe "**INPUT NUMBER**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a try for this batch file :

```bat
@echo off
Call :inputbox "Please enter a number:" "Box Title"
echo You entered %Input%
Start "" G:\testfolder\test.exe %Input%
pause
exit /b

:InputBox
set "input="
set message=%~1
set Title=%~2
echo wscript.echo inputbox(WScript.Arguments(0),WScript.Arguments(1)) >"%temp%\input.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%Title%"') do set "input=%%a"
exit /b
```